# Eloquent collide column names

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

users: `id`, `name`, ...

companies: `id`, `name`, ...

I have a `scope` with a `LIKE` operator, And I use it to search in both `users.name` and `companies.name` as follows:

```php
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, string $term = null)
{
    $query->join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'users.company_id');

    $term = $term.'%';

    $query->where('users.name', 'like', $term)
        ->orWhere('companies.name', 'like', $term);
}
```

Action:

```php
$users = User::query()
    ->search($request->input('q'))
    ->with('company')
    ->paginate();
// ...
```

Since `name` was used in both tables, Laravel can't distinguish between them, so it ends up filling the `users.name` with a `companies.name`:

[image]

The view looks like this:

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
    // ...
        <th scope="row">{{ $user->id }}</th>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td> // wrong: this gives the company.name
        <td>{{ $user->company->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    // ...
@endforeach
```

One solution to solve this is by using `select` and some aliases, but that would be a nasty solution.

Any **good** solution?

**Update 1**: I don't want to use `whereHas` since it's slower than joining when it comes to using the `LIKE` operator.

**Update 2**: another solution is to alias the `companies.name` and the `users.name` as follows:

```php
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, string $term = null)
{
    $query->join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'users.company_id')
        ->select(['*', 'companies.name as company_name', 'users.name as user_name']);
}
```

```
<td>{{ $user->user_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->company_name }}</td>
```

This works fine, but if (for any reason) I want to get rid of the searching capability, I also need to modify the view, so a dependency has been introduced here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some experiments, I found that using the `whereIn` clause is faster and more convenient than using `join`/`whereHas`:

```php
$query->where('name', 'like', $term)
    ->orWhereIn('company_id', function($query) use ($term) {
        $query->select('id')->from('companies')->where('name', 'like', $term);
    });
```

The action remains the same:

```
<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->company->name }}</td>
```

And as I said it's much faster than `joining` and `whereHas`.

Here is my benchmark:

- 600ms: `whereHas`.
- 500ms: `join`.
- 130ms: `whereIn`.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rewrite the search-scope to search for the company name through relations and using `whereHas()`, instead of joining it in. That way you never have ambiguous column names when using that scope.

It would generate a different query, but you would end up with the same result.

```php
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, string $term = null)
{
    $term = $term.'%';

    return $query->where('name', 'like', $term)
        ->orWhereHas('company', function($query) use ($term) {
            return $query->where('name', 'like', $term);
        });
}
```

Comment: `whereHas` is slower than joining when it comes to using the `LIKE` operator; I can clearly see the difference by using the MySQL `EXPLAIN` command.

Comment: Probably very negligible difference. If you're very worried and `join` performs better, you can always just do `select('users.*')`, but I would go with the `whereHas()` approach.